# Put an Image webpart (Image/Image gallery) on the top of a Modern SP page with Powershell (PnP)

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, powershell, image, pnp-powershell

I need to communicate an important information (picture) on Team Site homepages so I decided to add on the top of every homepages an Image Webpart (to know : homepages already has some webparts).
I uploaded the picture in the SP 'Site Assets' folder and then tried to proceed by executing the following Powershell command :

```
Add-PnPClientSideWebPart -Page ModernPage -Section 1 -Column 1 -Order 1 -DefaultWebPartType Image -WebPartProperties @{imageSource ="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/SiteAssets/MyImage.jpg"}
```

The command works fine and add the webpart to the page, BUT AT POSITION 2 !!!

[image: My image on position 2...]

Is there a way to force my webpart to be on position 1?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code snippets:

> ```
> Set Properties -Order 0
>
> Add-PnPPageWebPart -Page $page -DefaultWebPartType ImageGallery -WebPartProperties $convertedjsonImagesss  -Order 0
> ```